# "read" a single key gives an error

Tags: bash

This simple script should read one letter:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -n 1 key
echo $key
```

But it gives the following error

```
read: Illegal option -n
```

Executed by hand `read -n 1 key` works though.

Comment: How are you running that script?

Comment: put `type read` in your script, and see what that is

Comment: read is a shell builtin
-n: not found
1: not found
key: not found

Comment: sh; yes that solved it running it with ./script.sh works

Comment: Another shell runs it then — I guess you have some other sh bastard installed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `-n` option to `read` is a bash extension, not found in some other shells. If you got the error `read: Illegal option -n`, it means you didn't run the script under bash. It's most likely that you ran the script under `/bin/sh`, and `/bin/sh` is not bash but dash (the error message is the one dash produces).

To run a script under bash, start it with a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line `#!/bin/bash`, make the script file executable, and call it by name. Since you have a shebang line, the problem may be that you ran `. /path/to/script` instead of `/path/to/script` from another script running under `/bin/sh`.

Comment: yes, not having the full path of bash script was the reason mine was failing.... thanks!